# Arrays length returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome Extension, and I use the chrome.storage API in it. I am not putting my full code here (as its over 200 lines), but I'm putting enough that will probably show what I'm trying to do.

**Content Script (a script injected into a webpage due to my extension)**:

```
....
var videos = []
var imgs = []
var img = this.getElementsByTagName('img')
var video = this.getElementsByTagName('video')
for (i = 0; i <img.length; i++){
    if (img[i].className == "FFVAD"){
        imgs.push(img[i].src)
        addselection(img[i].parentNode.parentNode)
    }
}
for (i = 0; i <video.length; i++){
    if (video[i].className == "tWeCl"){
        videos.push(video[i].src)
        addselectionV(video[i].parentNode.parentNode)
    }
}

function addselectionV(e){
    e.style.border = "2px solid red"
    console.log(videos)
    for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++){
        chrome.storage.sync.set({['video'+i]: videos[i]}, function() {
          console.log('Value is set to ' + videos[i] + ' and key is set to ' + ['video'+i]);
    })

   chrome.storage.sync.set({vcount: videos.length}, function() {
      document.querySelector('.selectionbar').innerHTML = "Item(s) selected: "+videos.length
    });
```

}

I noticed that it wasn't working, so I added `console.log(videos)` to print the item in the array. It was there, so I did `console.log(videos[0])` and it was also there too. I looked in the developer console and noticed during my `for` loop, `videos.length` is returning undefined. Which is strange because I seem to have set everything up correctly. ([image of the console here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezzLe.jpg))

Comment: You are looping over `videos` variable in a loop over `video` variable, within the one you add items to `videos`... That's pretty a mess

Comment: @quirimmo I may have made a simple mistake in my code but could you please explain more on what you're talking about? It all seems right to me

Comment: inside your second for, you loop over `video`, you call `videos.push` and then `addselection`. Inside `addselection` then, you loop over the `videos`

Comment: @quirimmo  I am looping through `video` which represents every `video` HTML element. Then, I'm adding that element's source (`video.src`) to the array, `videos`. I then loop through videos to find the item I just added to the array and put it's value in `chrome.storage`. At least that's what I think I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) it looks like the chrome storage API runs asynchronously. What is most likely occurring is the console.log fires before the item is put in storage which is why you are getting undefined.

Comment: how would I make changes to my code to make it work?

Comment: The modern solution is to load the [WebExtension polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) and use async/await as shown in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @NickCodes for telling me that chrome.storage is asynchronous. So, I modified my code to make it asynchronous and it works perfectly fine!

```
function addselection(e){

    var fetchData = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve();
        });
    };
    function appendOutput (i,item) {
        fetchData(item).then(function () {
            chrome.storage.sync.set({['image'+i]: item}, function() {
                console.log('Value is set to ' + item + ' and key is set to ' + 'images'+i);
            })
            chrome.storage.sync.set({count: i}, function() {
                c = i + 1
                document.querySelector('.selectionbar').innerHTML = "Item(s) selected: "+ c
            });
        });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
        console.log(imgs[i])
        appendOutput(i,imgs[i])
    }

}
```